# strange css behaviour after using laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In combination of `Twitter Bootstrap` and `laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer` I have the following visual differences:

**BEFORE** using the PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer
[image]

**AFTER** using the PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer
[image]

Any suggestions, how to solve this issue?

I've also created a [bug tracker entry](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer/issues/71).

---

**EDIT:**
PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer seems to echo things outside the DOM.

If I run this Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="container">

    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the expected result.

But with an echo in the first lines, i get this broken buttons.

```
<?php
    echo 'test';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="container">

    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can guess some CSS properties from Laravel snippet are overriding the Twitter Bootstrap elements. It is better to show us a demo of the code or a live implementation rather than the image which is unfortunately of little help.

Comment: there are no changes in any css. It looks like there is an PHP `echo` somewhere